# Firefox extension applies the required edits on the website only once, how to detect the website every time it's opened

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

**Summary**

I'm new to the firefox extension and I'm not a web developer.
but I'm trying to make an extension that removes a specific element by class name.
Every time I refresh, close the tap or the browser, and re-open them, it seems like the extension doesn't remove the element.

Note: I checked the element class and it's the same, and If I disabled and re-enabled the extension the element gets removed.

**The manifest.json file**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "bla bla bla",
    "description": "Remove bla bla bla",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
      "64": "icons/icon.jpg"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches":["https://www.example.com/"],
        "js": ["background_script.js"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "64": "icons/icon.jpg"
      }
    }
}
```

**The background.js file**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_2cNrC')[0].remove();
```

When I load the extension for the first time in the Temporary Extensions, the wanted element gets removed from the website.

If I closed the tap or the browser and re-open it the element is not removed.

**What I tried to do:**

- I tried this manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "bla bla bla",
    "description": "Remove bla bla bla",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
      "64": "icons/icon.jpg"
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background_script.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches":["https://www.example.com/"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "64": "icons/icon.jpg"
      }
    }
}
```

- I tried to play around with the permissions, but nothing useful.
- I read Mozilla documents for the extensions, but I couldn't figure out how to detect the website every time it's opened.

Comment: That first version should work (although you've confusingly called your script `background_script.js` - it's a content script). The second version won't work because background scripts can't directly access the content of web pages. Depending on how the page is loading you may want to consider wrapping your code in a timeout until the element appears, and then remove it.

Comment: The first version is working, but once I refresh the website, close tap or the browser, and re-open the website, the element doesn't get removed like the extension doesn't work unless I disable it and re-enable it.